# regex.findall returns a dict instead of list

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm trying to extract result from a shell command. The reason i need to use shell inside python is: because i need to use Golang binary.

```
cmd = f'echo {domain} | /root/go/bin/crawler -subd
```

The go-binary `crawler` should output "a string that contains a json". First, i need to extract json from that string by using regex.

```
import regex
regu = regex.compile(r'\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}')
cmd = regu.findall(cmd)
```

The main goal is: to extract a json value from `findall` result.

```
cmd = cmd['status']['http']
for i in cmd:
   if i['codes']=='200':
      stuff
   else:
      stuff
```

Above fails because `findall` returns a `list` and not a `dict`. As another attempt, i'm trying to dump the result using `json` pkg.

```
import json
dummy = json.dumps(cmd)
cmd = dummy['status']['http']
```

But using `json.dumps()` returns unnecessary `\` infront of each string.

```
{\'status':{\'http':{\'codes': \'200'}}}
```

This means that i need to use another `regex` or others; to remove `\`. Meanwhile when using findall it returns:

```
['{'status':{'http':{'codes':'200'}}}']
```

How can i turns findall result into pure `dict` so it can extractable when using `dummy['status']['http']`?

UPDATE 1:
Another attempt is using `groupdict` and `finditer`:

```
regu = regex.compile(r'\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}')
cmd = regu.finditer(cmd)
cmd = cmd.groupdict()["statuses"]["http"]
```

it casting yet another problem.

```
AttributeError: '_regex.Scanner' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
```

UPDATE 2:
Someone might curious about the `crawler` output:

```
b'time="2022-08-04" msg="starte"\ntime="2022-08-04" level=dbg msg="finished"\n{"status":{"http":{"codes":200}}}\n'
```

I had to use `regex` to remove all the unnecessary comment.

Comment: shouldn't you be using json.loads instead?

Comment: don't parse json with a regex, use a json parser… please provide the original json returned by your tool

Comment: @Barmar Oh thanks. I really do love Python's naming """conventions""". Will delete.

Comment: yes, i have tried using json.loads() no luck @FaridFakhry

Comment: Thread updated to include tools output @mozway

Comment: what does `crawler` return? Give us an exmple of what the data looks like.

Comment: Refresh the page, already updated @tdelaney

Comment: Oh, right, missed that post. mozway seems like the right answer. Your json is on the last line, just load it.

Comment: Sorry about that, at first i think it's not good to put codes in a comment. So i just leave a "it didn't work" comment. It's true that the "didn't work" can be on my part. About the double encoding; at first i thought that ```json.dumps``` will tamper the json from the list ```['{'json':'json'}']``` into something ```{'json':'json'}```, that's my false logic. It's true that it tampers the json but also do a second encoding wich carried ```\```, thank you for the reminders on that. @tdelaney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the json is in the last line and your output is named `out`:

```
import json
cmd = json.loads(out.decode('utf-8').strip().rsplit('\n', 1)[-1])
print(cmd)
```

output:

```
{'status': {'http': {'codes': 200}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only get a dictionary if you have named capture groups in the regexp; those captures will be put into the `groupdict` attribute of the `Match` object, which you can get using `re.search()` or `re.finditer()`. But you don't need a dictionary. Just get the single match of the regexp, and call `json.loads()` to parse it as JSON.

```
import regex
regu = regex.compile(r'\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}')
cmd = json.loads(regu.search(cmd).group())
```